# AnimationNavigationPage is only sliding left to right instead of right to left

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I'm using the **AnimationNavigationPage** nuget package (found [here](https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin/AnimationNavigationPage)) to try and create a page slide animation going from right to left. So far it seems that all I'm able to get is left to right and it doesn't reflect when I change the animation type / subtype.

I'm sure I'm just missing something small but for the life of me I can't see it.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using FormsControls.Base;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PageNavigationExample
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
// by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : AnimationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
}
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<controls:AnimationPage
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FormsControls.Base;assembly=FormsControls.Base" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="PageNavigationExample.MainPage">

<controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>
    <controls:SlidePageAnimation Duration="Short" Type="Slide" Subtype="FromRight"/>
</controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>

<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Main page" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <Button Text="Main page button"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
</controls:AnimationPage>
```

And then just basic content pages for navigation purposes that I haven't modified...Page1, Page2, etc.

What am I missing here to just get the slide animation to slide in from the right when I click a button and slide in from the left when I click the Back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And then just basic content pages for navigation purposes that I
>   haven't modified...Page1, Page2, etc.

Have you let your Page1, Page2, etc to inherit `AnimationPage` and set the `PageAnimation`?

for example:

app.xaml.cs :

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AnimationNavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : AnimationPage
{
  public MainPage()
   {
    InitializeComponent();
   }

  private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
   }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<controls:AnimationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FormsControls.Base;assembly=FormsControls.Base"
         x:Class="App18.MainPage">
<controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>
    <controls:SlidePageAnimation Duration="Medium" Subtype="FromRight" />
</controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Main page" 
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <Button Text="Main page button"
        Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
</controls:AnimationPage>
```

Page1.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Page1: AnimationPage
{
    public Anim2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<controls:AnimationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
          xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FormsControls.Base;assembly=FormsControls.Base"
         x:Class="App18.Page1">
<controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>
    <controls:SlidePageAnimation Duration="Short" Type="Slide" Subtype="FromRight"/>
</controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</controls:AnimationPage>
```

the effect like:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing :)